# Android R file attributes are not recognized in my java code?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project, R file attributes are not recognized, for instance:

> Layout Cant be resolved or is not a field

```
package com.example.belfm;

import android.R;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class belfmActivity extends Activity {

        private static final int REQUEST_PATH = 1;
        String curFileName;    
        EditText edittext;
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.Layout.belfm_Activity);
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }

    public void getfile(View view){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, FileChooser.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent1,REQUEST_PATH);
    }
 // Listen for results.
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        // See which child activity is calling us back.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        curFileName = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
                        edittext.setText(curFileName);
                }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Please go through this page, before asking a Question , http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @playmaker420 on setContentvIEW(.R.Layout.belfm_Activity); i got error that said  "Layout Cant be resolved or is not a field", thanks

Comment: use setContentView(R.layout.belfm_Activity); .As @SankarGanesh mentioned please go through that link before you post a question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do the following I assume your using ADT.

1) Go to Project -> Clean as shown below.

[image]

2) See is there any problem in the Problem Window near to your console. check for any build path errors as shown below.

[image]

[image]

3) if everything is fine, go through your code.

4) I have noticed that your first line of import code , 
your **importing import android.R;** the android.R file contains the d**efault layout and components**, your trying to **access the layout and components created by you**  ,so please **change to that android R to your R file** by just seeing the **package name under your gen folder** as shown in the picture 2.

For Instance , if your gen folder show

> com.myexample.android

, then your R should be

> com.myexample.android.R

, this you have defined in your **AndroidManifest.xml** as shown below.

[image]

5) **Please follow Java Coding Styles**, For Instance your c**lass Name first Letter should be Capital Letter** like this BelfmActivity not be belfmActivity. Refer this https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html

6) I also suggest you to **read some basic examples** and then start your programming https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html
and also you can read from my blog too http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not there but I think you are facing problem that your code is not identifying your xml file
change import android.R; to your main package
like this import com.example.belfm.R;

and change Layout to layout 
your L is capital main isue is this

Answer (score 0):

`import android.R` has been included at the top of your code. Remove that line and `Ctrl+Shift+O` (include all required imports). The layout and all the resources associated to your project will be from `com.yourproject.package.R` and not from `android.R`. So ensure you import the correct R.java file in your code.